# Cant update button title after request with completion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im making an http GET request in separate class and call it inside subclass of UITableViewCell 
What i want is to show the count of array objects on button title after request, but its shows 0

here is my code:

```
class ReportAnIssue: UITableViewCell {
 var issuesArray = [Issue]()
 var openedIssuesArray = [Issue]()
 var closedIssuesArray = [Issue]()

@IBOutlet weak var openedIssuesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var closedIssuesButton: UIButton!


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let maker = UserProfileMaker()
    maker.request() {  issuesArray, openedIssuesArray, closedIssuesArray,  success in
        self.issuesArray = issuesArray
        self.openedIssuesArray = openedIssuesArray
        self.closedIssuesArray = closedIssuesArray
        // here array.count == 1
        self.openedIssuesButton.setTitle("Opened Issues: \(self.openedIssuesArray.count)", forState: .Normal)
        //here I'am getting 0 in title, but in fact it should be one
    }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should dispatch the call on the main queue, try that:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

     self.openedIssuesButton.setTitle("Opened Issues: \(self.openedIssuesArray.count)", forState: .Normal)
})
```

I believe the request is made in the background queue but all of the UI related operation must be done on the main one.